# Why use $\mu$-calculus and not LTL,CTL,CTL*?

Tags: logic, simulation, linear-temporal-logic, mu-calculus, computation-tree-logic

It is known that the temporal logics LTL,CTL,CTL* can be translated/embedded into the $\mu$-calculus. In other words, the (modal) $\mu$-calculus subsumes these logics,
(i.e. it is more expressive.)

Could you please explain/point me to papers/books that elaborate on this matter.
In particular, are there concrete fairness, liveness, etc. properties not expressible in the temporal logics but in the $\mu$-calculus?

Answer (score 9):

As for a $\mu$-calculus formula not expressible in CTL*, see [this post](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16164/ctl-and-mu-calculus/16165#16165).

As for texts on the subject, you are likely to get further ahead by reading papers, as these topics are not covered in many books.
Still, the [Handbook of Modal Logic](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=urINMvvsT5MC&pg=PA24&dq=handbook+of+model+checking&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ToxyUuncBaOI7Aazj4GYAQ&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=handbook%20of%20model%20checking&f=false) may be a good start.

As for papers, try:

[Expressive power of Temporal Logics](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.tau.ac.il%2F~rabinoa%2Fconcur02.ps.gz&ei=6q9yUo73Mo6ThQfLtYHQBQ&usg=AFQjCNGFK6qpx_gBPOsA0paNfLnwiS02cg&sig2=v0yFZGHuJhYKXnEPLjlrZA&bvm=bv.55819444,d.ZG4)

[This PhD thesis](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CEMQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hec.unil.ch%2Flogique%2Frecherche%2Fphd_ale.pdf&ei=VrByUuzLBJG7hAeFrIFY&usg=AFQjCNG2F93WWWq7YZ9AmttPYa3qysAuXw&sig2=jRwIDAxiLXil4dmnyrf6qw&bvm=bv.55819444,d.ZG4)

[Emerson's Model checking and the Mu Calculus](http://cc.ee.ntu.edu.tw/~farn/courses/FMV/FMV.Ref2.pdf)

And there are many more. Just google terms like "expressive power", "mu calculus" and "temporal logics".

Comment: Thanks for the example and suggestions. Could you please suggest any relevant papers? I remember seeing some in the past but have hard time locating them now...

Comment: Added papers to the answer.

Comment: There is [a book on modeling with mCRL2](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/modeling-and-analysis-communicating-systems) now (for a rough idea of its content, see [the book announcement](http://eatcs.org/beatcs/index.php/beatcs/article/download/313/295)).

Answer (score 6):

The $\mu$-calculus is strictly more expressive than LTL, CTL and CTL*. This is a consequence of a few different results.

The first step is to show that the $\mu$-calculus is as expressive as temporal logics. The main idea for encoding these logics comes from recognizing temporal properties as fixed points. At a very informal level, least fixed points allow you to express properties of a finitary nature and greatest fixed points apply to infinitary properties. For example, *eventually $\varphi$* in LTL defines that there is an instant in the finite future at which $\varphi$ is true, while *always $\varphi$* states that $\varphi$ is true at an infinite number of future time-steps. In terms of fixed points the eventually property would be expressed using a least fixed point and the always property using a greatest fixed point. Following such an intuition temporal operators can be encoded as fixed point operators.

The next step is to show that the $\mu$-calculus is more expressive. The main idea is alternation depth. Fixed points alternate if a least fixed point influences the greatest fixed point, and vice-versa. The alternation depth of a $\mu$-calculus formula counts the number of alternations that occur in it. The operators in CTL can be encoded by $\mu$-calculus formulae with alternation depth $1$. The operators in CTL* and LTL can be encoded by $\mu$-calculus formulae with alternation depth at most $2$. However, the alternation hierarchy of the $\mu$-calculus is strict, which means that increasing alternation depth in a formula allows you to express strictly more properties. This is why people say the $\mu$-calculus is more expressive than these temporal logics.

Some references:

1. The initial arguments that the $\mu$-calculus subsumes several logics appears in [Modalities for Model Checking:Branching Time Logic Strikes Back](ftp://ftp.cs.utexas.edu/pub/techreports/tr85-21.pdf), Emerson and Lei, 1985.
2. The translation of CTL into the $\mu$-calculus is straightforward. You can find it in the book on [*Model Checking*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262032708) by Clarke, Grumberg and Peled. You can also find it in [*Model Checking and the $mu$-calculus*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.33.916) by Emerson or in Ken McMillan's [dissertation](http://www.kenmcmil.com/thesis.html).
3. The translation of CTL* into the $\mu$-calculus is involved. Rather than the original, indirect translation, I suggest the paper of Mads Dam on [Translating CTL* into the modal mu-calculus](http://www.lfcs.inf.ed.ac.uk/reports/90/ECS-LFCS-90-123/).
4. There is a simpler translation of LTL into what is called the linear-time $\mu$-calculus, in which the modalities operate over traces and not states. See [Axiomatising Linear Time Mu-calculus](http://www.lfcs.inf.ed.ac.uk/reports/95/ECS-LFCS-95-324/) by Roope Kaivola.
5. The alternation hierarchy is studied in [The modal mu-calculus alternation hierarchy is strict](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/jcb/Research/althi-preprint.ps.gz) by Julian Bradfield and in [A hierarchy theorem for the $\mu$-calculus](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-61440-0_119) by Giacomo Lenzi.

All this is about expressivity not about utility. In practice, people don't usually specify properties as $\mu$-calculus expressions because they might find temporal logics easier to work with. The industrial specification languages differ from both temporal logics and the $\mu$-calculus in their syntax and their expressive power.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer! Regarding your comment on utility: suppose I want to use a μ-calculus model checker, but specify things in temporal logics, which is easier. Is there a technique (even better, a tool) that automatically translates formulae in any of these logics (CTL,CTL* or LTL) to the μ-calculus? Thanks!

Comment: SMV internally translates CTL into $\mu$-calculus. Not sure what tool explicitly does this.

Answer (score 3):

It is well known that $\mu$-calculi can express properties that "count modulo a constant", e.g., "*all even steps visit a $A$-state*" which is captured by something like $\mu X.A \land\Box\Box X$. Such properties cannot be stated with the standard TL modalities Until and Next since these modalities are 1st-order definable. See [D. C. Kozen's 1983 article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975%2882%2990125-6).